# How can I create dynamic routes?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, acl

I have this path:

```
http://localhost:8000/home
```

I want when a regular user opens path above, then I call this controller:

```
mainPage@index
```

But when a admin opens that path, then I call this controller:

```
panelPage@index
```

So as you see, I'm looking for *"dynamic routes"* kinda .. Is implementing that possible? In other word, can I call two different controllers for admin and regular member ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can create middleware groups. Are you using Laravel's auth? Have you already created something like an AdminMiddleware?

Comment: @JanWillem I understand is current user either admin or regular member like this: `@if( Auth::user()->admin ) { // admin } else { // regular member }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best practice, you could use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) to sort-out and categorize your routes and controllers.

In this - relatively simple - case, you could also use something like this (in your routes file):

```
if(!is_null(Auth::user()))  {
  // first check if user is logged in, else Auth::user() will return null
  $uses = 'mainPage@index';
  if(Auth::user()->admin) {
    $uses = 'panelPage@index';
  }
  Route::get('/', $uses);
}
```

**Update**

Or you could wrap everything inside this if statement in an auth middleware group, like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
   $uses = 'mainPage@index';
    if(Auth::user()->admin) {
     $uses = 'panelPage@index';
    }
    Route::get('/', $uses);
});
```

Also make sure that your users table has a column named 'admin'.

Comment: your code throws this error: `ErrorException in routes.php line 18:
Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case to use [Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) to filter HTTP requests.

You could also do something conditional in your routes file, like:

```
if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
    Route::get('/', 'panelPage@index');
} 
else {
    Route::get('/', 'mainPage@index');
}
```

Depending on what your application looks like, you can define isAdmin() in your User model. This is a very simple example where you have a column called role_id and id nr 1 equals admin. If authenticated user is admin, it displays true, otherwise false:

```
public function isAdmin()
    {
       return Auth::user()->role_id == 1;
    }
```

A more dynamic and advanced approach would be to create a role table, and associate the role with the user with a role_user pivot table.

If you want it to take a step further, you can create a permissions table and associate the role with the permissions with a permission_role pivot table. Then you can in your application define that a permission is needed to be able to do an action and add all the permissions that a given user role has in that pivot table. Then you just check if the user (with a specific role) has the given permissions.

Comment: It throws this error: `Call to a member function isAdmin() on null`

Comment: isAdmin is just a sample in this case, you need to define what "isAdmin()" is. How you define it depends on how you've designed your application. If you have a "role_id" in the users table, then you can create a method called isAdmin() that checks if the corresponding role_id is the one of an admin. So when you call isAdmin() you check to see if the user has the right role_id. I will update the answer with an example.